# Why does the price term in Vega disappear for a European call option?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, mathematical-modeling

In my course, I have been asked to prove a number of statements about "the Greeks" from the Black-Scholes model for pricing a European call option with no dividends and a strike price of $K$. One of the problems was to prove that $\nu$ (Vega) was positive. To prove the fact, I began by differentiating the Black-Scholes model: 
$$
C_t = S_t\Phi(d_1(t))  - K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi(d_2(t)),
$$
where all of the variables are defined as is done [typically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526217/why-the-vega-of-the-black-scholes-model-is-at-its-maximum-for-at-the-money-opt), and $S_t$ is equal to 
$$
S_t = S_0\exp\left(\left(b - \frac 1 2 \sigma^2\right)t  + \sigma B_t\right),
$$
with $B_t$ a Brownian motion. Now, when I take the derivative w.r.t. $\sigma$ of $C_t$, I find that 
$$
\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial\sigma} = \frac{\partial S_t}{\partial \sigma}\Phi(d_1(t)) + S_t\Phi'(d_1(t))\frac{\partial d_1(t)}{\partial \sigma}  - K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi'(d_2(t))\frac{\partial d_2(t)}{\partial \sigma}.
$$
Using the fact that $S_t\Phi'(d_1(t)) = K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi'(d_2(t))$, and that 
$$
\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial \sigma}  - \frac{\partial d_2}{\partial \sigma} = \sqrt{T - t},
$$
I find that 
$$
\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial\sigma} = \frac{\partial S_t}{\partial \sigma}\Phi(d_1(t)) + \sqrt{T - t} K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi'(d_2(t))\frac{\partial d_2(t)}{\partial \sigma}.
$$

Obviously, I now need to solve $\frac{\partial S_t}{\partial \sigma}$. In so doing, I find that 
$$
\frac{\partial S_t}{\partial \sigma} = (B_t - \sigma) S_t,
$$
which makes my final answer that 
$$
\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial\sigma} = (B_t - \sigma) S_t\Phi(d_1(t)) + \sqrt{T - t} K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi'(d_2(t))\frac{\partial d_2(t)}{\partial \sigma}.
$$
However, all the sources that I can find (e.g. [here](http://www.econ-pol.unisi.it/fm10/greeksBS.pdf), [here](http://finance.baylor.edu/garven/papers/garven_options.pdf) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526217/why-the-vega-of-the-black-scholes-model-is-at-its-maximum-for-at-the-money-opt)) report that Vega is just equal to 
$$
\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial\sigma} =  \sqrt{T - t} K e^{-r(T - t)}\Phi'(d_2(t))\frac{\partial d_2(t)}{\partial \sigma}.
$$
Is there something that I am doing wrong? I suspect that I am doing something wrong w.r.t. the inclusion of $B_t$, as that seems strange. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does stock price change with respect to volatility?

Comment: Isn't the change in stock price w.r.t. volatility given by the $\frac{\partial S_t}{\partial \sigma} = (B_t - \sigma)S_t$ term?

Comment: $S_t$ is the stock valuation's price at time $t$, which is a given / constant. You do not model it as the expected effect of Brownian motion.

Comment: Oh- that makes sense. We would only model its evolution over time as the expected effect of Brownian motion?